# I am trying to fetch user meta value by current user id or user role

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to fetch user data  from user-meta table by current user id or by user role . but right now I am not able to fetch this . this query is running good . any help

```
<?php   $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'ua_user_phno' AND  meta_value = '4189985296' LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A);
            print_r($posts);
    ?>
```

Comment: Why you have used $wpdb->usermeta you could simply use table name here

Answer (score 1):

you can get the user meta value by its key and id simply by this code

```
<?php 
  $user_id = 9;
  $key = 'last_name';
  $single = true;
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  echo '<p>The '. $key . ' value for user id ' . $user_id . ' is: ' . $user_last . '</p>'; 
?>
```

`$user_id` for the current user id or the required id of user

`$key` for the meta value you want to fetch

reference link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta